# Invalid conversion identifier '.'

Tags: c, printf, type-conversion, scanf

So I'm writing code to interpret a users input about whether they're payed an hourly wage or set salary. I've started a switch statement and the first statement within it is a `printf()` & a `scanf()` statement that reads

```
printf("Enter hourly wage: ");
scanf("\n $%5.2d", &hRate);
```

the compiler keeps giving me an error message for the `scanf()` statement that says: *"invalid conversion specifier `.` "*.

I've gone through and checked the program, and I've tried changing the statement, taking out the `$` and what not, and nothing seems to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just put `scanf("\n %d", &hRate);`

Comment: Why are you using "5.2" inside scanf ? 
Just use scanf("%d", &hRate).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` does not allow an optional `.` in a conversion specification.

`.` can be used with some `printf` conversion specifiers.

```
scanf("%5d", &hRate);    // allowed
scanf("%5.2d", &hRate);  // not allowed
printf("%5.2d", hRate);  // allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

`'.'` is not a valid part of a format specifier for `"%d"`.

Anyway, the value you need to read is certainly of the form " $ xxx.xx"

Read the hourly wage as a floating point value.

```
printf("Enter hourly wage: ");
double dhRate;
if (scanf(" $%lf", &dhRate) != 1) Handle_BadInput();
// covert to cents if needed
int hRate = round(dhRate * 100.0);
```

Another approach would read as dollars and cents

```
printf("Enter hourly wage: ");
int hRate_d, hRate_c;
if (scanf(" $%d.%d", &hRate_d, &hRate_c) != 2) Handle_BadInput();
// covert to cents if needed
int hRate = hRate_d * 100 + hRate_c;
```

A better solution would read the entire line using `fgets()` and then parse it using `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc.